# Get instances from list based on priority

Tags: java, list

I need a way to methodize objects based on priority.

```
private void placebyPriority(int amount){

    List<ChestContainer> high = getChestsByPriorty(ChestPriority.HIGH);
    List<ChestContainer> medium = getChestsByPriorty(ChestPriority.MEDIUM);
    List<ChestContainer> low = getChestsByPriorty(ChestPriority.LOW);

    //here methodizing based on priority

}
```

So for example the amount = 20. The amount of elements of high is 5, the amount of elements of medium is 14 and the amount of elements of low is 10. Now I want to methodize the amount variabele spread over the lists (based on priority: high -> medium -> low). So all the elements of high will be .place(); then we got 20 - 5 = 15 left. Then all of the medium list element will be place(); and we got 15 - 14 = 1 left. The last one will be picked from the low list.

I've no idea how to do this in an efficient way. I just need those objects based on priority from the list and use them like this: `chestContainer.place();`.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the example you have? For example, why does amount==20 mean that high==5, medium==14, and low==10?

Comment: I don't understand how "medium" (14) is higher than both "high" and "low"

Comment: Well see it like this: I need to spread the amount over a list, a split that list into high, medium and low. High is the list that must be methodized first, then medium then low. So if I got 20 to spread and the size of the highlist is 5, I will first pick the 5 from the highlist then from the mediumlist, then the lowlist.

Comment: oh i see. Is the total of the count of each of the 3 lists supposed to equal 20?

Comment: When you say "size of high is 5" do you mean that the list `high` will have 5 elements?

Comment: You need something like this (but more efficent?): `List total = high.addAll(medium).addAll(low); for (CC cc : total.sublist(0, amount)) cc.place;`?